# Fast method to solve transcendental equation for a range of parameters?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, transcendental-equations, programming

I have an equation of the form

$t + e^{Ax} + e^{Bx} = 0$

This is a transcendental equation, and I would use a Newton-Raphson algorithm or `uniroot` in `R`, to solve for $x$.

I am interested in finding the solution to this equation for a range of values of $t$.

Do I need to repeat the same algorithm for every value of $t$, or is there any way in which I can use the solution for a particular $t$ to calculate the solution for other values of $t$?

---

Edit: In my specific problem I have $A > 0$ and $B<0$.

Comment: Can you say something about the range of values that can be taken by parmaeter $A$ and $B$, positive, negative, $[0,1]$, any value ?

Comment: Sure, I added the restrictions on $A$ and $B$ from my specific problem to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that transforms the initial problem with 2 parameters into a 1 parameter issue, easier to tackle.

Set $C=B/A$ (a negative number because $A>0$ and $B<0$).

Let us make a (bijective !) change of variable

$$u=e^{Ax} \ \ \iff \ \ x=\frac{1}{A}\text{ln}(u)\tag{1}$$

Important remark : $u>0$.

The initial equation

$$x+e^{Ax}+e^{Bx}=0 \tag{2}$$

is thus transformed into

$$\underbrace{t+u+u^C}_{f(u)}=0\tag{3}$$

or, geometrically, into the intersection of

$$\begin{cases}y&=&u^C& \ \ \text{(curve with asymptotes)} \\y&=&-u-t& \ \ \text{line with slope} \ -1\end{cases}\tag{4}$$

Fig. 1 illustrates (4).

Three cases can occur (due to the fact that the straight line hits the $y$ axis in $-t$) :

- either zero solutions when $t<t_0$ for a certain $t_0$.
- (exceptionally) one solution when $t=t_0$,
- 2 solutions when $t=t_0$,

> and in this case which one do you desire ?
>
> I have assumed here that we are looking for the root with the highest magnitude.

The choice of the initial value is directed by the diagram : if we take the initial value $u=-t$, for big values of $-t$, we will be already rather close to the final value.

The following Matlab program applying Newton iteration is very efficient :

```
A=1.;B=-2.5;C=B/A;
t=-3;
u=-t, % initialization
for k=1:4, % 4 iterations are usually enough
   u=u-(t+u+u^C)/(1+C*u^(C-1)), % Newton iteration step u = u-f(u)/f'(u)
end;
x=(1/A)*log(u), % solution x=x(t)
t+exp(A*x)+exp(B*x), % checking that this value is (almost !) zero
```

[image]

*Fig. 1 : (case  $A=1, B=-2.5, C=B/A=-2.5$. Horizontal axis is for $u$ variable). Curve with equation $y=u^C$ and two straight lines with resp. equations $y=-u-t_0$ and $y=-u-t$ for two different values of $t$ ($t=-3$ and $t=t_0 \approx 1.818$); Newton recurrence relationship with initial value $u_0=3$ gives final value $u_5=2.9321...$ out of which $x=1.0757...$.*

Comment: I have completely re-written my text that is now a full-fleshed solution. It can be improved, of course. Can you tell me if it agrees you ?

Comment: +1. I appreciate the reduction to a one parameter problem. It occurred to me that usual error formula for Newton's method $e_{n+1}^2 = - \frac{1}{2} \frac{f''(\xi_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ allows us to approximate the distribution of the initial guesses needed to quickly solve *any* for any $t$ in a bounded interval. This suggests to me a whole set of nice practice problems of the non-linear-solve, table-look-up, interpolation type.

Comment: @Carl Christian Yes, this issue could be extended as a nice student's project for example for a  recap of a certain number of Numerical Analysis methods...

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you!